# Timestamp differences - just a little bit confused

Tags: php

Today i tried to take some timestamps before and after executing code snippets.

Simplified

```
<?php

 $before = time();
 $test = array();

 // Waste some time
 for($i=0;$i<1000000;$i++) {
      $test[] = rand(1,2);
 }

 $after = time();

 var_dump($before);
 var_dump($after);
```

The value from before and after are exactly the same?! Correct me, if i am wrong, but they should be different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`time()` returns the number of seconds since the Unix epoch and the whole process took only less than a second. That is why you aren't seeing any difference. Replace [`time()`](http://php.net/time) with [`microtime(true)`](http://php.net/microtime) to get more accurate results.